# Making sense of soundMixer.computeSpectrum

Tags: actionscript-3, math, audio

All examples that I can find on the Internet just visualize the result array of the function `computeSpectrum`, but I am tasked with something else.

I generate a music note and I need by analyzing the result array to be able to say what note is playing. I figured out that I need to set the second parameter of the function call 'FFTMode' to true and then it returns sound frequencies. I thought that really it should return only one non-zero value which I could use to determine what note I generated using Math.sin function, but it is not the case.

Can somebody suggest a way how I can accomplish the task? Using the soundMixer.computeSpectrum is a requirement because I am going to analyze more complex sounds later.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I can, of course, but there is NO bug. I copied code generating a note and code used to visualize the sound from the documentation. Unfortunately, there is NO code for analyzing the data and no whatsoever explanation of how to do it or ... maybe I am missing something.  So, the question is more theoretical, not about a bug.

Comment: Sorry, the code's happened to be too long to provide here, but you can find it in the documentation. Again, I want to use  result of the computeSpectrum function to figure out one main frequency corresponding to the generated sound

Comment: For a continuous tone of 440hz what number do you get from your FFT results? You'll need to take that `-1 to 1` range and do some math (eg: calculate against Sampling Rate etc) to get the result of 440...

Comment: VC.One, what do you mean? What exactly math I need to program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FFT** will transform your signal window into set of Nyquist sine waves so unless `440Hz` is one of them you will obtain more than just one nonzero value! For a single sine wave you would obtain 2 frequencies due to aliasing. Here an example:

[image: aliasing]

As you can see for exact Nyquist frequency the FFT response is single peak but for nearby frequencies there are more peaks.

Due to shape of the signal you can obtain continuous spectrum with peaks instead of discrete values.

Frequency of `i-th` sample is `f(i)=i*samplerate/N` where `i={0,1,2,3,4,...(N/2)-1}` is sample index (first one is **DC** offset so not frequency for `0`) and `N` is the count of samples passed to **FFT**.

So in case you want to detect some harmonics (multiples of single fundamental frequency) then set the `samplerate` and `N` so `samplerate/N` is that fundamental frequency or divider of it. That way you would obtain just one peak for harmonics sinwaves. Easing up the computations.

Comment: Do I need to take Max value and its index out of FFT array - it will be f(i) and to calculate samplerate, which is f(i)/i*N ?

Comment: @Graizik `samplerate` is frequency the sound was sampled with (on SoundCard or whatever) so usually 11025 or 44100 or 48000 or 192000 Hz  I do not know if you can change it on your platform, `N` is tweakable but **FFT** use only powers of 2 (so 1,2,4,8,16,32,...). So you need to find combination `samplerate/N` that is as close as possible to your fundamental frequency. then find the biggest peak in the FFT result and that should be fine. In case of aliasing (you know you got just one tone but 2 peaks then the tone frequency is somewhere between the two)

Comment: @Graizik what are your values? ... `samplerate, N, tone frequency,` peak `i` (counting from 0) ? and is the peak alone or not ?

Comment: I write a program which should be independent of SoundCard properties. I generate sound as it suggested in the AS3 documentation  t.writeFloat(Math.sin((Number(c+p)/Math.PI/2))*0.25); p is a position, c an index from 0 to 8096. I change 2 to some number (I need to figure out yet to what change to get the right music notes) And I want to identify every time what note was played by analyzing FFT. I don't know what samplerate is in my comp. It shouldn't matter I think or how to get it ?

Comment: @Graizik the sample rate is `1/time_step` in your sinwave : therm `Number(c+p)/Math.PI/2` so `c = <0,8096)` now you need to know how long the 8096 samples are playing that will give you `T [s]` and samplerate is `8096/T [Hz]` then you want to modify your tone generator like `sin((p+c)*2*PI*samplerate/(8096*tonefreq))`

Comment: "how long the 8096 samples are playing that will give you T [s]" How I can find it?

Comment: @Graizik measure ....  or use some utility that tells you what samplerate you are using for sounds ... if you are not configuring it then it may change from version to version of your platform or even machine to machine ... try to search your docs for samplerate settings ... you can not do any sound generation nor playback without it ...

Comment: I think that I can figure out samplerate programmatically and it will make my program independent of hardware used. What is tonefreq you mentioned? time_step is, probably, measured time divided by the number of samples (8096)? Things become more clear thanks to you.

Comment: @Graizik `tonefreq` is frequency of your generated tone (you mentioned `440 Hz`)  the idea is the buffer holds `8096` samples and is played for `T` seconds so there should `T*tonefreq` periods (`2*PI`) inside 8096 steps of your sinwave that is the what the equation in previous comment does

Comment: The formula you mentioned previously sin((p+c)*2*PI*samplerate/(8096*tonefreq)) is it your advice on generating the right music tones?

Comment: @Graizik yes otherwise you just generate sinwave on the blind without knowing its frequency ... Also your `tonefreq < samplerate/2` otherwise serious problems will occur ...

Comment: samplerate is the value we set in a program to change the sound quality? 11025 or 44100 or 48000 or 192000 Hz

Comment: @Graizik could be ... yes definatelly yes the values are common sample rates

Comment: Thanks a lot!  :)